# jsUnit and build.xml

Tags: ant, hudson, jsunit

So I want a build.xml file that I can invoke from Hudson to run my jsUnit tests. However, the build.xml file has a few things that it needs to ... I guess run the unit tests. One of things it needs are these browser files such as ie.exe or firefox.exe. However on Ubuntu I have no clue as to where these browser files are.

If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate perhaps
 - a sample build.xml file that can run multiple tests (through Hudson).
 - OR a way to reference the "browser files"
 - OR a description of a simpler/better alternative of jsUnit

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You can use the command which... i.e. which 'firefox'... it will show the path that your firefox executable is located, so you can use that in your build file! I haven't really configure a build.xml, so I cannot really help you there...

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds like you are looking for the firefox executable. On Ubuntu, I believe that is located at:

```
/usr/bin/firefox
```

There is no ".exe" extension.